# Power series of $f(z)=\frac{z^2+1}{z^2-z^4}$ near $z_0=i$

Tags: complex-analysis

My problem is that I can't use the power series of $\frac{1}{1-z}$ because we are looking at a ball around point $z_0=i$, and not all points there justify $|z|<1$. So I don't know what to start from. This doesn't seem something with exponent or trigonometric functions series. Trying to find n'th derivative seems very hard.

I did manage to find an answer using partial fractions and the power series of $\frac{1}{1-z}$, but I can't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints.

$$\frac1{z^2-z^4}=\frac1{z^2}+\frac{1/2}{1-z}+\frac{1/2}{1+z}$$

$$\frac1{z^2}=\left(-\frac1z\right)'$$
And for $|h|<1$:
$$-\frac1{i+h}=i\sum_{n=0}^\infty(ih)^n$$

$$\frac1{1-(i+h)}=\frac1{1-i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac h{1-i}\right)^n$$

$$\frac1{1+(i+h)}=\frac1{1+i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-h}{1+i}\right)^n.$$

Answer (score 0):

The geometric power series
$$
\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n
$$
is expanded around $z = 0$, which is why it only converges inside the disk centered at $0$.

But we can expand a power series for a holomorphic (complex analytic) function $f$ around any point $z = z_0$ in its domain:
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!} (z - z_0)^n, 
$$
and it will converge on $|z - z_0| < R$, the disk of radius $R$ centered at $z_0$. (It also might converge for some or all of the points on the boundary circle if $R < \infty$, but that's not important here.)

When you're looking for a series expansion **near $z_0 = i$** that's the hint that you should expand about that point. You could just grind out derivatives and hopefully spot a pattern, then show it's true for all $n \geq 0$, say by induction, then evaluate them at $z_0 = i$ and compute coefficients. But this is usually difficult if not impossible, and certainly can be tedious.

Instead, whenever we can manipulate a *known* series (like you suggested when expanding about $z_0 = 0$), it's easier. So, define a new complex variable $w = z - z_0$, so that $z = w + z_0$. Now, substitute this into your function. In this case, we can let $w = z - i$ so that $z = w + i$ and
$$
\frac{1 + z^2}{z^2 - z^4} 
= \frac{1 + (w + i)^2}{(w + i)^2 - (w + i)^4}.
$$
Now simplify/manipulate it to try to see it as a transformed expression of some familiar functions, say involving geometric series, etc. (I'll leave this algebraic work to you.)
You should be able to write this as a series centered at $w = 0$ (that's the point of shifting to this new variable), so that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n w^n, 
$$
where $(a_n)_{n = 0}^{\infty}$ is the sequence of Taylor coefficients.
Now, substitute $w = z - i$, to obtain something of the form
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z - i)^n.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure how to do that algebraic work... tried plugging what u wrote after using partial fractions, nothing seems to be a manipulated form of the geometric series